# How to automate the deployment from s3 bucket to an ec2 instance by using aws CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

a war file will be uploaded to S3 bucket, Requirement is when a new war file is uploaded to s3 bucket it should be deployed automatically to an ec2 instance through AWS CodeDeploy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an AWS CodePipeline to trigger AWS CodeDeploy deployments based on updates to S3 resource. You can refer the sample pipeline creation described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-s3.html.